# Trouble installing meteor

Tags: meteor, installation

I'm trying to run meteor on a shared debian host (1and1.com). It installs OK, but when I try to run meteor, I get this:

> **(uiserver):u51918509:~/meteor > meteor**
>
> /kunden/homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/meteor: line 133: //homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: No such file or directory

but the file appears to be there:

> **(uiserver):u51918509:~/meteor > ls -al //homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node**
>
> -rwx---r-x 1 u51918509 ftpusers 9216272 Oct 28 12:52 //homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node

and when I try to run it, I get

> **(uiserver):u51918509:~/meteor > /homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node**
>
> -bash: /homepages/25/d272133409/htdocs/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.ftql1v++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, on linode x64, seems to be related to arch.

Remove previous meteor installation

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/meteor ~/.meteor
```

Download meteor script

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ > meteor.sh
```

Edit meteor.sh and force 32bit arch:

```
 72   ### Linux ###
 73   LINUX_ARCH=$(uname -m)
 74   #if [ "${LINUX_ARCH}" = "i686" ] ; then
 75     PLATFORM="os.linux.x86_32"
 76   #elif [ "${LINUX_ARCH}" = "x86_64" ] ; then
 77   #  PLATFORM="os.linux.x86_64"
 78   #else
 79   #  echo "Unusable architecture: ${LINUX_ARCH}"
 80   #  echo "Meteor only supports i686 and x86_64 for now."
 81   #  exit 1
 82   #fi
```

Install meteor.sh

```
sh meteor.sh
```

source: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2610